# Kafka Connect and Custom Queries

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, kafka-producer-api

I'm interested in using the Kafka Source JDBC connector to perform to a publish to Kafka, for when an Invoice gets created. On the source end, it's broken up into 2 tables Invoice, and InvoiceLine.

Is this possible, using custom queries. What would the query look like?

Also since its polling, what gets published could contain one or more invoices in a topic?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use custom queries. From the [docs](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-jdbc/source-connector/index.html#incremental-query-modes):

> **Custom Query**: The source connector supports using custom queries instead of copying whole tables. With a custom query, one of the other update automatic update modes can be used as long as the necessary `WHERE` clause can be correctly appended to the query. Alternatively, the specified query may handle filtering to new updates itself; however, note that no offset tracking will be performed (unlike the automatic modes where `incrementing` and/or `timestamp` column values are recorded for each record), so the query must track offsets itself.

Comment: In this custom query, would a message in the topic represent an invoice with the multiple invoice line in the form of an AVRO schema. or would there be  multiple messages for each line of the invoice. If its the latter, is there a method to make that as a single message with an invoice and multiple invoicelines